# Can I set a python while loop to run until nothing changes?

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, arcgis

I have written a python script in ArcGIS that selects features that intersect. It needs to keep repeating until all relevant features are selected. At this point the selection will stop changing. Is it possible to set a loop to keep repeating until the number of selected features is the same as last time it looped? I can get the selected features using the `arcpy.GetCount_management()` method.

I've set the number of selected features to be a variable:

```
selectCount = arcpy.GetCount_management("StreamT_StreamO1")
```

Then this is the

```
mylist = []
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("antiRivStart","ORIG_FID") as mycursor:
    for feat in mycursor:
        mylist.append(feat[0])
        liststring = str(mylist)
        queryIn1 = liststring.replace('[','(')
        queryIn2 = queryIn1.replace(']',')')

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management('StreamT_StreamO1',"ADD_TO_SELECTION",'OBJECTID IN '+ queryIn2 )

arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("antiRivStart","INTERSECT","StreamT_StreamO1","","ADD_TO_SELECTION")
```

So what I want to do would effectively be:

```
while selectcount == previousselectcount:
        do stuff
```

but I don't know how the while loop is supposed to be constructed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close to how you would monitor the change in the number of features. Consider the following.

```
previousselectcount = -1
selectcount = arcpy.GetCount_management("StreamT_StreamO1")
while selectcount != previousselectcount:
        do stuff
        # update both counts at the end of what you want to do in the while loop
        previousselectcount = selectcount
        selectcount = arcpy.GetCount_management("StreamT_StreamO1")
```

Note the not equals operator (`!=`) in the while loop condition.

Answer (score 0):

[python wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop)

If selectcount or previousselectcount are of type float, you probably wants to do a range
aka

```
 while selectcount >= previousselectcount+c:
      ....
```

with c a positive constant very close to zero.